# PHP: WHY LDAP filter does not work with "_" symbol?

Tags: php, ldap

I need your advices about getting information from ldap server.
My filter is simple but it doesn't work!

```
'filter' => "(u_someinfo=*)"
```

I discovered that symbol "_" in filter name generates error "Bad search filter".
If I write code looking like that:

```
'filter' => "(usomeinfo=*)"
```

It works even ***usomedata*** does not exist in ldap! 
Probably there must be some approuch to resolve it , but I cannot what I have to do?
So , any ideas?

Comment: thank you my friend for your correction, english is not my mothertongue but i am trying to write without errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen an underscore in an attribute name; I don't think underscores are permitted in attributes.

I found this... https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2251#section-4.1.4

From reading, I think only letters, numbers and hyphens are permitted. I don't recall ever seeing a hyphen either though. I personally have only used letters and numbers to create attribute names.

> *A specification may also assign one or more textual names for an
> attribute type.  These names MUST begin with a letter, and only contain
> ASCII letters, digit characters and hyphens.  They are case insensitive.*

Comment: thanks i realized that error in underscore is. Thank you